# Xcode 5: How to tell Xcode where localized files should go

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization, resources

**Situation:**
In Xcode 5, you have a resource such as a nib that is not localized, and then you localize it by clicking a language Localization checkbox in the File inspector of the Utilities pane on the right hand side (see picture below).

**Behavior:** For me at least, Xcode creates an lproj folder at *project-root/lang.lproj/* and puts the resource file in it. That is, the lproj folder is inside same parent folder as the .xcodeproj file itself.

**Desired Behavior:** Xcode should put the new resources into my already-existing lproj folders, which are in a subfolder or the project root. That is, *project-root/resoures/lang.lproj/*.  It should not create a new lproj file in another location.

Is it possible to instruct Xcode to look for & create lproj folders in a different location from the folder where the .xcodeproj resides?

[image: Xcode Localization inspector]

Comment: good question. Especially: why does Xcode sometimes create folder on the top level, sometimes on a sublevel of a project?